# CSS tooltip doesn't work in WordPress HTML file

Tags: css, wordpress, hover

Right now I'm making nicely formatted CSS files for our temporary WordPress site, until the new site is ready. After making a CSS style sheet and pretty HTML files, I found they didn't work in WordPress if they were inline in a post, but instead I had to put them in a separate raw HTML file (using "WP File Manager" plugin to upload them to a separate folder.) After that, the way they display on the site matched what they look like on my HDD or on my personal (LAMP) test site (using Safari 10.1.1 OS X), and if I display source in my browser it looks identical to what I uploaded.

Then I created a tooltip style with CSS following the tutorial on w3schools. In the style sheet I define "edit" as a style for changes I made to the original text

```
.edit { /* changes made, */
    color: navy;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.edit .tooltip {
    font-size: medium;
    visibility: hidden;
    background-color: navy;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    width: 20em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    border-radius: 6px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}
.edit:hover .tooltip{
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Then (per the tutorial) I add "tooltip" text inside "edit" text

```
<h5 class="edit">¶ Then shall be said or sung the following Canticle.
<span class="tooltip">This canticle is most commonly used.</span></h5>
```

On my HDD and my personal site, the tooltip is invisible until I hover over it and then it pops up a balloon.

But when I load it onto WordPress, the hidden text is always visible inline, as if the "tooltip" style is ignored. To work around this bug for now (so I don't have to re-edit the HTML files), I was able to disable and hide all the tooltips by defining the tooltip style as

```
.edit .tooltip {
    visibility: hidden;
    font-size: 0%;
}
```

This suggests that the "tooltip" is being seen, but some aspect of the hidden part is being parsed differently on WordPress.com.

So is there some CSS style or property that WordPress could be using that causes my text to be shown? Any way to pre-emptively override this with CSS? Should I write a JavaScript that goes through and manually hides the tooltips?

Any experiments I should try to make it go away?

PS: This is different than the question at [CSS Tooltip will not work on WordPress page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45740828/css-tooltip-will-not-work-on-wordpress-page) because my text is shown inline.

Answer (score 0):

You are saying:

> But when I load it onto WordPress, the hidden text is always visible inline, as if the "tooltip" style is ignored.

This is an indication that the file with the styles for tooltip is loaded before other css styles are loaded. Thus files that load last override what's been loaded before.

For debugging, try adding `!important` to your tooltip style rules like this:

```html
.edit .tooltip {
    visibility: hidden !important;
    font-size: 0%;
}
```

and see if that makes any changes.

Then, modify your WordPress files so that your tooltip styles are loaded last. That will allow you to remove the `!important` flag. (because using that flag is not a best practice and should be avoided whenever possible)

Comment: Thanks so much for the suggestion. I tried the !important with but with no change. I'll have to check and see how to change the order of loading styles.

However, I am now seeing a problem with at least one browser (Brave 0.19) on my local HDD without any WordPress at all.<br>

`<a name="Benediction"></a><dt><span class="caps">The</span>
grace of our Lord Jesus Christ,
<span class="addcross">&#10016<span class="tooltip">The sign of the cross is historically made for the Benediction.</span></span>
…<i>Amen.</i></dt>`

Comment: Sorry for formatting problem. I see the hidden tooltip text with just straight HTML and no other CSS/text loading. So it suggests something more basic problem either with my CSS, or how I'm formatting the HTML that uses the tooltip style.